# convert from jpg to mp4 by ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, mp4

I have 320 jpg(320x574) images which I have recorded them with 2004 fps. I want to make a .mp4 video of them. I have run below codes in cmd (win7) and it just make a video of jpg number 320 and if I go for this ('*.jpg') insted of 320 it does not work. I really appreciate any help.

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i C:\data-Sam\320.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\data-Sam\out.mp4
```

Comment: 2004 fps makes your video of length 80/501 seconds (under 0.2 seconds)!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Depending on your file names you'll want:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i /path/to/file/image%3d.jpg test.avi
```

The `image%3d` would be for files named: `image000.jpg`, `image001.jpg`, `image002.jpg`, etc.

If your files are named `image0.jpg`, `image1.jpg`, `image2.jpg`, etc. then you'd use `/path/to/file/image%d.jpg`.

See [FFmpeg image2 demuxer examples](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Examples-3)

Comment: My files name are sorted from 1.jpg to 320.jpg . I have to change them or I still could use them as it is.

Comment: when I run the code which you left, this attention note pops up in the cmd that Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.

Comment: when I run the code which you left, this attention note pops up in the cmd that Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it. and asked me to use other muxer or -vsync 2. Indeed I have recorded my images which is 320 jpg with 2000 fps. I use this code: ffmpeg -f image2 -i Path/To/File/filename%d.jpg -r 2000 -pix_fmt yuv420p path\to\result\test.mp4    what do you think?

Comment: I am using ffmpeg binary on windows it doesn't take %d in option.

Comment: Trying to do this on Windows, as far as I can tell, it doesn't work. I only get the first frame.

Comment: You can also use `-pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg'` if the file order presented by `ls` works for you.

Answer (score 15):

I can show you an example here,

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 60 -i path/filename%03d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -crf 18  -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

- **f**: force format
- **r**: frame rate
- **i**: input files assuming your files are `filename001.jpg`, `filename002.jpg`, ...
- **vcodec**: video codec
- **crf**: constant rate factor (0-51). 17-18 is (nearly) visually lossless. See [Encode/H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)
- **pix_fmt**: pixel format

Answer (score 7):

You have other option like :

- **framerate** = Set the frame rate for the video stream. It defaults to 25
- **-r** = set frame rate

  ```
  ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i Path/To/File/filename%3d.jpg -r 5 -y Path/To/File/test.mp4
  ```

Comment: what's the difference between -framerate and -r, if they both set the frame rate?

Answer (score 6):

## Use `cat`

finally, I came up with a solution, it is using cat to get a `.mkv` and then convert it to `.mp4`

navigate to the folder that contains the `.jpg` files

```
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -i - output.mkv
```

and then

```
ffmpeg -i output.mkv -codec copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 4):

The main folder in it is ffmpeg.exe, the Your_files folder and the Result folder.
In the Your_files folder, upload a series of images.
Bat file will sort them in the order of the queue by name.
The finished video will be in the Result folder.

```
echo off
color a
set a="Your_files\*.jpg"
set b="Result\video.mp4"
set c=ffmpeg
set f=-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -crf 20
set tmp="Result\list.tmp"
for %%f in (%a%) do (@echo file 'file:%cd%\%%f' >> %tmp%)
%c% -y -f concat -safe 0 -i %tmp% %f% %b%
cd /d Result
del /f /q list.tmp
exit
```

**-c:v libx264** - We will encode in the MP4 format with the x264 codec.
**-loglevel 16** – Show all errors, including ones which can be recovered from.
**-r 30** – FPS frame rate. It takes effect after all filtering, but before encoding the video stream.
**-crf 20** – Constant Rate Factor (CRF) is a quality setting (and rate control). values from 0 to 51, where lower values will result in better quality at the expense of higher file sizes. Higher values mean more compression, but at some point you will notice quality degradation. The default is 23.

Comment: Great answer and explanation!

Answer (score -5):

> I am using ffmpeg binary on windows it doesn't take %d in option.

You are using `cmd.exe`, Right? Then do it like:

```
"file%d.jpg"
```

`cmd.exe` uses `%PATH%` to imitate `$PATH` used in real shells, so gets confused with `file%d.jpg`.