# Flutter: Can we save a Canvas/CustomPainter to a gif or continuous pictures or event a video?

Tags: flutter

Can we export custom painter used animation controller to a gif image or continuous images or event a video such as mp4 file?

Answer (score 4):

Yes I did it one time (2 years ago) and I converted a Flutter Animation to a mp4 file. unfortunately I couldn't find the code. please follow the steps to make what you want.

1. capture your widget with `RenderRepaintBoundary` like below code
   https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderRepaintBoundary/toImage.html

   ```
    class PngHome extends StatefulWidget {
      const PngHome({super.key});

      @override
      State<PngHome> createState() => _PngHomeState();
    }

    class _PngHomeState extends State<PngHome> {
      GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();

      Future<void> _capturePng() async {
        final RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderRepaintBoundary;
        final ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
        final ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
        final Uint8List pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
        print(pngBytes);
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return RepaintBoundary(
          key: globalKey,
          child: Center(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: _capturePng,
              child: const Text('Hello World', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

    }
   ```
2. save each image like this

   ```
   import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
   import 'dart:io';

   Uint8List imageInUnit8List = // store unit8List image here ;
   final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
   File file = await File('${tempDir.path}/image.png').create();
   file.writeAsBytesSync(imageInUnit8List);
   ```

---

3. you need to capture each frame of your Animation and save it to a directory. with special naming for example (`1.png`,`2.png` .... `1000.png`)

   ```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      child: theChildWidet() // important use child for performance 
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {

        CaptureScreenAndSave(_controller.value) /// <- capture each frame

        return Transform.rotate(
          angle: _controller.value * 2.0 * math.pi,
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
    }
   ```
4. install `ffmpeg` https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter and use it to execute FFMPEG command

   ```
   import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter/ffmpeg_kit.dart';

   FFmpegKit.execute('your command').then((session) async {
   final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

   if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {

    // SUCCESS

   } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {

    // CANCEL

   } else {

    // ERROR

   }
   });
   ```
5. search for a command to convert your images with `ffmpeg` to Gif Or Mp4 (some thing like these [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22966561/6813907) or [Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg))

Comment: Thank you for the response. In the second step, does that mean I have to create a loop to run 1000 times and capture images each time? Should I have a delay set with each loop? Also, doesn't that take a lot of time to process - just to run the loop?

Comment: your welcome !,@Danny , in your Animation builder in Builder method, you can call captureAndSave method. because build method calls on each frame of your animation.  I updated the answer

Comment: we need 25 Frame per second but Flutter renders 60 frame per second, so I think  we can improve performance with skipping some frame and using compute for multithreading https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute-constant.html

Comment: what I tested isn't heavy . so I think multithreading is enough . no need to skip frames.

Comment: Thank you again! I will look into it. I wasn't aware of `compute constant`. I think this is a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot)  library. by wrapping the parent container with Screenshot library you can convert widget to multiple images and those images can be converted to a gif but I think it is tricky, not efficient, and difficult to implement. you can give it a  try.